# jQuery object inside object inside foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a question more about logic, rather than technical details.

I'm saving the content of a form created by JavaScript using objects, I've managed to save the main form content successfully but I'm unable to save a child form's content.

**Here's a JSFiddle which better shows the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/96wstepj/**

1.) Go to "Pricing Per Night" > "Seasonal Pricing" and click "Add Seasonal Price Filter", fill out the fields

2.) Then click "Add Price Rule" and fill out the fields

3.) Click "Save All" and you'll see all the content is correctly shown in JSON format in an alert

4.) Now click "Add Seasonal Price Filter" again, fill out the fields, and click "Add Price Rule" and fill out the fields (so now you have 2 seasonal price filters, and one price rule in each)

5.) Click "Save All" and you'll see the price rule content is repeated in each seasonal filter (see the "price" object key)

**Problem: https://ibb.co/mgZHFQ**

This is the function which is adding the form content in an object:

```
function get_seasonal_price_rules() {

    var obj1 = {};

    var obj2 = {};

    $("#price-per-night .seasonal-filter-wrapper-outer .price-rule-wrapper-outer").each(function() {

        $(this).children('div').each(function(index2) {

            obj2[(index2 + 1)] = {

                standard_adult_weekday: $('#price-per-night input[name=standard-adult-weekday-' + (index2 + 1) + ']').val(), 
                standard_adult_weekend: $('#price-per-night input[name=standard-adult-weekend-' + (index2 + 1) + ']').val(),
                standard_child_weekday: $('#price-per-night input[name=standard-child-weekday-' + (index2 + 1) + ']').val(),
                standard_child_weekend: $('#price-per-night input[name=standard-child-weekend-' + (index2 + 1) + ']').val()

            };

        });
    })

    $(".seasonal-filter-wrapper-outer").each(function() {

        $(this).children('.seasonal-filter-wrapper-inner').each(function(index) {

            obj1[(index + 1)] = {

                seasonal_date_from: $('#price-per-night input[name=seasonal-date-from-' + (index + 1) + ']').val(), 
                seasonal_date_to: $('#price-per-night input[name=seasonal-date-to-' + (index + 1) + ']').val(), 
                seasonal_adult_weekday: $('#price-per-night input[name=seasonal-adult-weekday-' + (index + 1) + ']').val(), 
                seasonal_adult_weekend: $('#price-per-night input[name=seasonal-adult-weekend-' + (index + 1) + ']').val(),
                seasonal_child_weekday: $('#price-per-night input[name=seasonal-child-weekday-' + (index + 1) + ']').val(),
                seasonal_child_weekend: $('#price-per-night input[name=seasonal-child-weekend-' + (index + 1) + ']').val(),
                price: obj2

            };  

        });
    })

    return obj1;

}
```

Appreciated any help!

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Not all the content is being added correctly in the JSON: https://ibb.co/mgZHFQ

Comment: A working example with all the HTML/CSS/JS is provided in the main description: https://jsfiddle.net/96wstepj/

Comment: you really should include all information in the qs itself, also it's hard to decipher what you mean in the image, if you simply supply the actual and desired output it would be easier to understand and debug.

Answer (score 0):

I did not look into it too much, but based on the input names it looks like you aren't tracking the "sub-index" numbers to avoid collisions. You wind up with this:

- seasonal filter 1

  - price rule 1
  - price rule 2
- seasonal filter 2

  - price rule 1
  - price rule 2

You'd want those price rules for filter 2 to be 3 and 4. An easier way would be to also add on the index number of the parent:

- seasonal filter 1

  - price rule 1-1
  - price rule 1-2
- seasonal filter 2

  - price rule 2-1
  - price rule 2-2

That will ensure you have unique input names so you can capture all your data properly.